# Visualforce <apex:relatedlist> List Name for External Sharing

Tags: visualforce

I am looking for the list name to put for the tag  on a Visualforce page for account to allow External Sharing. I already have a connection set up but cannot find the correct name for the related list.

I have tried  and some variations of that but all give errors saying that the list does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those built-in related lists (like field histories) that you can not define a Visualforce relatedList component for.

You will need to create a custom component that reads the `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` table, filtering on column `localRecordId` for the parent SObject.  (That is, show only shared Opportunities on the Opportunity VF page; show shared Accounts on the Account VF page).

The actions will need to be defined explicitly using URLFOR functions to match the OOB External Sharing URLs.

I have this same issue but haven't gotten around to writing the component yet; instead, I provide an escape for authorized users to view the standard page layout (and hence the External Sharing related list)

The 'escape' is a commandLink component like this:

```
<apex:commandLink id="gotopagelayoutView" value="Sysad View"    target="_blank"     
        rendered="{!$Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'}" 
        styleClass="somePleasingStyleClass"         
        action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.View,Opportunity.id,null,true)}"/> <!-- last arg is noOverride=true -->
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Professional Edition so I don't think I can create custom components. I didn't think about trying your workaround but I think that should work for me. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer with the 'escape' mechanism